# How to run vbs file in pos-build or pre-build event in vs2005?

Tags: vbscript, visual-studio-2005, pre-build-event

I have some projects inside a solution, but because the needs of x64 and win32 i have diferent releases and some diferent files for a setup project. I need to unpack a zipfile before build the setup project. I have a vbs file that woks well to unzip the file, but the point is that i dont know the code that execute a vbs file in pre-build.

Comment: I don't know if vs2005 is different so maybe I got this wrong but in vs2013 you can execute any executable in those steps. So you can just run "wscript.exe vbsfile.vbs" no special code or anything...

Comment: its working! make it an answer and i will accept  @Syberdoor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute any executable in the pre and post build steps so you can add

```
wscript.exe path_to_vbsfile.vbs
```

to call your script.